# Increase Font in this Flash Browser App

Tags: flash

I would like to use this app, but I find that the font is unreadable on my browser (FF and Chrome).  My standard broswer function to increase the font does not work.  Does anyone know of a way to increase this font?

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'built-in' way to change font size in Flash as there is with browsers.

Unless the developer(s) have built that functionality themselves (which no-one ever does), there's not much you can do, short of getting hold of the source code.

Comment: That's unfortunate.   The developer must be under 40  :)